# Running fn_trace_gettable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

Can I read a tracefile on 2000 SQL server using `fn_trace_gettable` without having to stop the trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, so long as you run it from the instance that the trace is executed from.

Comment: But it complains that:
File ********* either does not exist or is not a recognizable trace file. Or there was an error opening the file.

Comment: I have scripted this trace(with required filters) and running it as TSQL when I want.
At present, I am stopping the trace, read it, load it to a table and restart it.

Rather than using fn_trace_gettable, can I just tell the trace to directly log it to the table when it finds something? This would be much more robust.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

also think about using rollover files. that way you can copy the full files to another machine and look at them while your trace is still running.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. I just want to read a trace while it is running in SQL 2000